# MongoDB vs Neo4j query

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, nosql

I'm comparing two NOSQL DBMS: MongoDB vs Neo4j.
In these databases I have some football teams with information about common name, official name, country, stadium, uniform, ecc...
In MongoDB the attribute uniform is an array that contains the colours of the uniform.
In Neo4j each colour is a node with a tone property. UNIFORM is the arc that associates a team to a uniform colour.

I made the same query on both of them and I want to evaluate the performance: the query is to find the common_name of all teams that have in their uniform green tone.
[image]

**Now, can I say that this query is more efficient in Neo4j than in MongoDB?**
I thought that in MongoDB I have to scan for each document the array uniform. Instead in Neo4j I have to visit the graph. I can't use the cursor.explain("executionStats") in MongoDB to see the executionTimeMillis because in my DB there are too few documents, but in Neo4j the query takes 25 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should certainly have more documents to test.  But a few things:

Firstly, you should have an index in Neo4j if you don't already.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :colour(tone)
```

That should allow Neo4j to find the node that you're looking for and then quickly browse to the appropriate `Team` nodes.  The standard for Neo4j labels, by the way, is UpperCaseFirstCamelCase.  See: http://nigelsmall.com/zen

Secondly, this is a small example of why it can be hard to compare databases with different paradigms.  In MongoDB you're representing colors (or colours ;) as a property, but in Neo4j you're representing it as a separate node.  That's not really the same thing as in MongoDB you have one entity and in Neo4j you have two.  In Neo4j you could also use a property on the `Team` nodes and just have your index there.

The thing is that MongoDB doesn't have a concept of joins/relationships.  So if you tried having a `colours` table then you're going to have more difficulty with Mongo.  I'd suggest having a larger domain model spanning at least 5-10 entities so that you can better compare.  You should especially thing about ways in which you might want to query/aggregate across entities.

If you'd like help getting a better feel for how to model in Neo4j, there's now a public users' Slack group with a modeling channel for help with such things.

Comment: Very good answer.
So, for example, I can compare normalized model with different collections of MongoDB with the arcs of Neo4j. In this case since join does not exist in MongoDB, I have to do more queries on different collections. Instead in Neo4j I have to visit the graph with more efficient than MongoDB. Right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  If you have indexes to find the start nodes then Neo4j can explore a sizable part of the graph's local space (that is, traversing from one node to another via relationships) very efficiently.  In Mongo you need to query one collection, get the result, then query the next set of data that you need, and so on.  Even SQL is better in that case ;)

Comment: Perfect thank you a lot. I'm going to compare Neo4j and MongoDB in this way.

Comment: Great, and again, feel free to drop by the Slack group!  There are a lot of people there happy to answer your questions (even if it means I can't earn StackOverflow points ;)